# What is this JavaScript reference syntax used in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, syntax

In Visual Studio 2012, I created a web application then found the following line in the default **_references.js** script that came with the project:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.8.2.js" />
```

What is this reference notation doing? This is confusing - isn't this just a comment, which shouldn't do anything? As I understand, a double slash (//) comments out a line in JavaScript. Is there anything special about triple-slash comments?

Comment: It's great that you know what you're writing about - we want to understand too, maybe if you gave a code example...

Comment: It is [a special comment to assist IntelliSense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287000/reference-path-re-javascript-intellisense) and is ignored by the compiler since it is just a comment.

Comment: @RaymondChen Post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see this article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb385682.aspx

and find **Reference Directives**

A reference directive enables Visual Studio to establish a relationship between the script you are currently editing and other scripts. The reference directive lets you include a script file in the scripting context of the current script file. This enables IntelliSense to reference externally defined functions, types, and fields as you code.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Triple Slash Directive and has many uses.

See this article

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html

> ... Triple-slash references instruct the compiler to include additional files in the compilation process....

Very useful in linking typings definitions... for example, the `mysql.d.ts` typings has the following reference to the node.js typings...

```
///<reference path='../node/node.d.ts' />
```